# Generate Facebook Export Event key

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, calendar, export, key

Is there a way to generate the Export Events key using the graph API? By this I mean when you go to events on Facebook and click "Export Events", it creates a link that looks like this:

webcal://www.facebook.com/ical/u.php?uid=XXXXXXXXX&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I want to know how to generate the "key=XXXXX" part.

Thanks

Comment: Hello,
did you find this answer. i have same issue. can you post you answer.

Comment: Nope never found an answer :(